# Editting a bigbluebutton's video

Tags: bigbluebutton

I want to delete a part of a bigbluebutton's video or to download it for editting. Do I have to use an API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the project manager for BigBlueButton.  The playback format for BigBluebutton is an HTML5 web page that uses popcorn.js to synchronize the playback of a VP8 encoded video (audio track + webcams + desktop sharing) and the slides (PNG images + SVG graphics) and chat (HTML text area).

We support marking segments during a session for playback using the Start/Stop record button.

There is no API to edit a recording, but you could modify the events.xml (the events file generated from a session) to add more Start/Stop recording marks and then submit the recording for re-processing.

Again, there is no API to do this, and you would needed to understand how the events.xml is formatted, but the pieces are there to build an interface to enable editing and re-processing.

For more information, see

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/recording.html

Comment: Is there any estandard to encode this into any single file format, or do you have any documentation on how could a team create its own viewer for it.